# Self created EXE file downloaded from internet not working

Tags: java, windows, exe

I have created simple jar and converted into .exe file using launch4j tool and its working fine, but when I uploaded that exe on server and downloaded from that server its not working. Why?

Please help me if anyone knows that issue

Comment: does it give any errors

Comment: Which tools did you use to upload and download. Did you compare file size?

Comment: I have cpanel and uploaded via cpanel file manager, it doesn't showing any error and file size is also same

Comment: Have you got the JVM installed?  Could it be Windows is blocking the executable because it sees it as a downloaded file from an untrusted source?

Comment: Yes JVM is installed because I'm using same machine where I have created exe.

Comment: windows is not blocking, when I'm running that exe splash screen appears then nothing

Comment: Try running the exe from the command line. Hopefully it will give some useful output.

Comment: I have tried to run exe from command line but it didn't show anything in console